# Apple Push Notification not working after changed Mac

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

since my old MacBook crashed and not able to revive, I have gotten a new macbook and load my project from SVN.

Because of this I faced problem with the code signing. So I deleted all my cert and provision profile from Apple developer and regenerated new set. I have successfully archive the app now.

Problem is the push notification is not working already. Even I have replaced re generated p12 on my server. My old app, ad hoc new app all don't receive message anymore.

Anybody can advise me where to check? Thanks.

Comment: r u cheking notifications in sandbox mode or prodcution mode

Comment: I tested on both development and sandbox (ad hoc). Both are not working. Not sure about production because it is not available on app store yet for the new version.

Comment: 1.sandbox should be fasle in ur  push sharpcode.2.once check provisoning profile status whether it's valid or not 3.once check entitlements for provioling profile 4.check device tokens bcoz the development and prodction r not the same

Comment: Check those possibilties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Siva for the suggestions, those are all valid checking. However I have done all these but still to no avail.

After dive deep into the code and Google around, finally found the culprit. It is due to Apple no longer support SSL and using TLS now. Have to update code in Push Sharp.

These are 2 related links:

1) https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/pull/369/files

2) https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/424